# pointer to a data member in C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli, pointer-to-member

How can I make a pointer to a data member in C++/CLI
for example

```
ref class team
{
  List<teamMember^> members;
  teamMember^ leader;     //the aim is to make it a pointer to an element in the list
  void changeLeader(teamMember^% member)  //member is an element from members
  {
    leader=member;  //doesn't reference and %member gave an error
  }
};
```

Comment: This is highly incompatible with the garbage collector, it moves objects when compacting the heap, thus invalidating pointers.  Use references and avoid pinning.  The posted code works fine when you drop %.

Comment: @user746277 : What is your use case here? Why is a handle of one of the elements in the list not sufficient?

Comment: @HansPassant: It would be incompatible only if a native pointer (`*`) or native reference (`&`) were used.  The tracking handle (`^`) and tracking reference (`%`) both play nice with gc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++/Cli **handles (^)** are analoguos to native pointers.
This code will work.

```
ref class teamMember
{
  public bool isLeader;
};

ref class team
{
  List<teamMember^> members;
  teamMember^ leader;     
  void changeLeader(teamMember^ member)  
  {
    if(leader != nullptr)
      leader.isLeader = false;
    leader = member;
    leader.isLeader = false;  
  }
};
```

Take a look at [this](http://www.functionx.com/cppcli/handles/Lesson06c.htm) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/books/CppCliInActionCh1Ex1.aspx) for more info.

Comment: There are pointers-to-members in C++/CLI -- [`interior_ptr<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0fh545k.aspx)

Comment: @ildjarn: Damn! Completely forgot about it. Thanks.